# Cannot impl Display for struct in Rust

Tags: rust

I've been following along [Rust by Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/) and couldn't achieve debug output of the struct (`Matrix` in the code below).

First things first, here are the versions;

- OS: macOS 11
- Rust: rustc 1.49.0 (e1884a8e3 2020-12-29)
- Cargo: cargo 1.49.0 (d00d64df9 2020-12-05)

While I was trying to do what's been asked on the 1st activity of  ["Activity" section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/primitives/tuples.html#activity) of "Tuples" step;

> "Add the fmt::Display trait to the Matrix struct in the above example"

I created a new Rust project via Cargo and created such structure;

```sh
$ROOT
├- Cargo.toml
└- src
   ├- main.rs
   └- mytuples2.rs
```

```
// src/main.rs

mod mytuples2;

fn main() {
    mytuples2::run();
}
```

and

```
// src/mytuples2.rs

use std::fmt;

// The following struct is for the activity.
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Matrix(f32, f32, f32, f32);

impl fmt::Display for Matrix {
  fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
    write!(f, "(({}) ({})\n ({})({}))", self.0, self.1, self.2, self.3)
  }
}

pub fn run() {
  let matrix = Matrix(1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2);
  println!("{:?}", matrix);
}
```

but unable to produce the following output;

```
((1.1) (1.2)
 (2.1) (2.2))
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help me as I'm a newbie. Thanks.

PS: Instead it writes `Matrix(1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2)`

Comment: `"{:?}"` doesn't use `Display` it uses `Debug`, try just `"{}"`

Comment: Thanks @kmdreko, you made me realize something. Please see the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Despite it's my fault I am going to answer it;

Deleting `#[derive(Debug)]` before the struct definition and changing impl to `impl fmt::Debug for Matrix {` (as opposed to `impl fmt::Display for Matrix {`) solved it.

No need to change `"{:?}"` to `"{}"` as the purpose is to print the struct in the debug format (thanks to @kmdreko).